# Scrapy, Scrapinghub and Google Cloud Storage: Keyerror 'gs' while running the spider on scrapinghub

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, scrapinghub

I'm working on a scrapy project using Python 3 and the spiders are deployed to scrapinghub. I'm also using Google Cloud Storage to store the scraped files as mentioned in the official doc [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#id1).

The spiders are running absolutely fine when i'm running it locally and the spiders are getting deployed to scrapinghub without any errors. I'm using **scrapy:1.4-py3** as the stack for the scrapinghub. While running the spiders on it, i'm getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 77, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 102, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 36, in from_settings
    mw = mwcls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/media.py", line 68, in from_crawler
    pipe = cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 95, in from_settings
    return cls(store_uri, settings=settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 52, in __init__
    download_func=download_func)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py", line 234, in __init__
    self.store = self._get_store(store_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py", line 269, in _get_store
    store_cls = self.STORE_SCHEMES[scheme]
KeyError: 'gs'
```

PS: 'gs' is used in the path to store the files like

```
'IMAGES_STORE':'gs://<bucket-name>/'
```

I have researched about this error, but there aren't any solutions as such. Any help would be of immense help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage support is a new feature in Scrapy 1.5, so you need to use `scrapy:1.5-py3` stack in Scrapy Cloud.